# Parameter types how to manupulate string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use ref from parameter here but this is not working:

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Creating template to deploy 3 ec2 instances in 3 different AZs",
  "Parameters": { 
    "CFCidrVPC1": {
      "Type": "string",
      "Default": "10.10.0.0/16"
    }         
  },  
  "Resources": { 
    "VPC1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC1"
        },        
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "False",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "False",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default"
      }     
    } 
  }
}
```

`CFCidrVPC1`: This is defined in parameters and I'm trying to use it in resources but I'm getting `Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unrecognized parameter type: string`

I don't want to put in CIDR value directly while creating VPC.

Is there any way I can define CIDR somewhere and later reference it?

Comment: Please format your code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Type` should be `String` with a capital `S`.

Comment: I am new to this coding and stuff .. your answer helped.. I cant believe i could not figure this simple stuff .. tough road ahead for me.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the green "tick" @SamirKhan. :)